# How do I delete tables that all have similar names

Tags: macros, sas

I want to use a SAS function such as

```
proc datasets nolist;
    delete lib.temp_something lib.temp_something2 lib.temp_something3;
quit;
```

Is there a shortcut to delete all tables with the same prefix so I dont have to manually type them out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to @Dwal

```
proc datasets lib=lib nolist nowarn;
delete temp_somthing:;
run;
```

Comment: If you library's name is `mylib`, then change `lib=lib` to `lib=mylib`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the colon wildcard `:` should do what you want.

```
proc datasets nolist;
    delete lib.temp_something:;
quit;
```

Comment: @neoman it does according to the documentation. It also works in set statements. You may need to move the lib to the proc datasets line, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: proc datasets lib=lib nolist;
    delete temp_something:;
quit;

@Reeza , yeah you are right, though this is the correct syntax.

Comment: very nice! was trying for ages with regex when this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this below

```
proc delete lib=mylib data = temp_something-temp_something3;
run;
```

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/022-2013.pdf